# What is the Drupal 7 version of FILE_STATUS_TEMPORARY?

Tags: files

My use case is that I want to set an uploaded file as `FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT` until I know it has been processed correctly by my custom module. Once that is done, I'm happy for Drupal to delete it. There used to be a `FILE_STATUS_TEMPORARY` in D6 but no more. What should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is strange, as `FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT` still does exist indeed. But the value of `FILE_STATUS_TEMPORARY` used to be `0`. So I suppose you can use anything that evaluates to zero: `FALSE`, `NULL`, `0`. Personally I have always used `0`.

But why set your file back to temporary to have it deleted by cron, why not just delete the file directly after processing? You can use [file_delete()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_delete/7) to do that.